# Waterproof vs water-resistant

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the dictionary definitions:

> - **Waterproof** means
> - not allowing water to go through
>     waterresistant.

On the other hand:

> - **Water-resistant** means:
> - Something that is water-resistant does not allow water to pass through it easily, or is not easily damaged by water.

My taking based on these explanations is that something which is **waterproof** doesn't let the water to pass through it while a **water-resistant** thing "might" would let it.

Is it the only nuance between these two qualities or there is something else I have to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only one of degree of protection.

A *water-resistant* coat could be OK in a light shower of rain, but you would still get wet in heavy rain. A *water-proof* coat should keep you dry in any amount of rain.

Comment: These two descriptions are frequently used of wrist watches to distinguish between those that will continue working after being quickly retrieved from water (water resistant) and those that will function underwater to a certain depth (water proof).